# Perpetual loading in sql server join query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query where i am joining 2 tables and in inner query when the table is  coming empty ,i am getting perpetual loading .Can anyone explain me why it is so?

Query--->

```
SELECT TRF.GroupId,
       'Brand imagery',
       ImageryId,
       'Brand' SelType,
       BCC.MasterId,
       BCC.CategoryId,
       SUM(TRF.[Weight]),
       COUNT(TRF.Respondent_Serial),
       QtrType 
FROM #tmpRespFrequency TRF  
JOIN (
    SELECT A.MasterId,
           A.Respondent_Serial,
           ImageryId,
           B.CategoryId
    FROM Brand_Imagery_Deepdive A 
    JOIN #BrandCategoryType B ON A.MasterId=B.SelId AND B.SelType='Brand' 
    JOIN #Measure M ON M.Metric='Brand imagery' AND M.MetricItemId=ImageryId
    WHERE B.CategoryId NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT CategoryId FROM Brand_Imagery_DeepdiveBase
    )
) BCC ON TRF.Respondent_Serial=BCC.Respondent_Serial
GROUP BY TRF.GroupId, ImageryId, BCC.MasterId, BCC.CategoryId, QtrType;
```

innner query which is coming empty if running separate is: -

```
(SELECT A.MasterId,
        A.Respondent_Serial,
        ImageryId,
        B.CategoryId
 FROM Brand_Imagery_Deepdive A 
 JOIN #BrandCategoryType B ON A.MasterId=B.SelId AND B.SelType='Brand' 
 JOIN #Measure M ON M.Metric='Brand imagery' AND M.MetricItemId=ImageryId
 WHERE B.CategoryId NOT IN (
     SELECT DISTINCT CategoryId FROM Brand_Imagery_DeepdiveBase
 )
)
```

BCC is EMPTY in short

Kindly suggest

Comment: Qualify ImageryId here `M.MetricItemId=ImageryId`

Comment: value is 51...its giving empty result...thats not a prob ...right? table joining with empty table should give empty result,not perpetual loading?

Comment: When I said "qualify" I mean add a table alias qualifier. E.g. `M.MetricItemId = A.ImageryId` or similar.